# Custom NSWindows

Tags: objective-c, nswindow

Is is possible to make a window act like a true heads up display? If not fully can a windows do any part of the following? Any pointers on finding information about how to code a window like this would be great.

1 - Be above everything?

- All other windows?
- On all spaces?
- Shown above the screensaver? [1]

2 - Be non interactive?

- Never get focus?
- Ignore all mouse clicks? *(ie. if the user click where the window is, what ever is under the window receives the click)*

[1] Shown above the screen saver would be a user settable preference (default to off). If the display is a big TV and the screen saver slide show is running, the user may sill want the display to be shown.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The bezels that appear when you change the screen volume/etc do this and I have seen third party apps do it. But I'm not exactly sure how it's done. I suspect you'll need to subclass NSWindow, select a relevant window level (I believe there are constants for this, and you can do something like `kConstantName - 10`. I'm not sure how to make mouse clicks "fall through" a window, but I suspect it's just a boolean flag somewhere. Make sure your drawing code is *very* efficient, I think it's going to be run every time any other app does any drawing. Maybe an NSImage cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want.  If you're looking for a full screen app here's [Implementing the Full-Screen Experience](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html).

Otherwise, you might be wanting to read [Window Layers and Levels](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/WindowLevel.html)

Here's an exert for convenience:

> There are a number of predefined window levels, specified by constants defined by the NSWindow class. The levels you typically use are: `NSNormalWindowLevel`, which specifies the default level; `NSFloatingWindowLevel`, which specifies the level for floating palettes; and NSScreenSaverWindowLevel, which specifies the level for a screen saver window. You might also use `NSStatusWindowLevel` for a status window, or `NSModalPanelWindowLevel` for a modal panel. If you need to implement your own popup menus you use `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel`. The remaining two levels, `NSTornOffMenuWindowLevel` and `NSMainMenuWindowLevel`, are reserved for system use.

Oh!  And I'm pretty sure you can't have *anything* over the screensaver.